# Getting all loaded jars' file path on runtime java 17

Tags: java, classloader, java-11, java-17

I have a solution that is basically code from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46709196
Code is compiled on jdk11 but I would like it to run on java17 runtime.

So, in runtime my class loader is `jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders.AppClassLoader`

Problem is, line `Field ucpField = classLoader.getClass().getDeclaredField("ucp");` throws NoSuchFieldException

Is there any way to access that field? I see in decompiled code that it moved up in hierarchy to BuiltinClassLoader `private @Stable URLClassPath ucp;` but cannot understand why reflection returns zero declared fields for `AppClassLoader`

Tried talking to chatgpt, answers were based on some Module magic, none of them worked

Comment: What’s wrong with the good old `System.getProperty("java.class.path")`? Why do you prefer messing around with undocumented internals?

Comment: @user16320675 thanks, I must have missed that. Changed line to `Field ucpField =   ((Class<?>) classLoader.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getDeclaredField("ucp");` and worked.
@Holger this gives me relative path as a String, above solution gives me an URL object with absolute path

Comment: `new File(relativPath).getAbsolutePath()` or `Paths.get(relativPath).toAbsolutePath().toString()`, whatever you prefer. Still no reason to mess around with Java internals.

Comment: @Holger Yes, you're right, I used system property with parsing to absolute path and worked, thanks!

Comment: _"Tried talking to chatgpt"_ ChatGPT is basically a very convincing bullshit generator. It might get things right occasionally, but in general it just makes up plausible sounding nonsense. Do not trust it, and do not use it to learn coding.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel although I agree that one should not blindly follow chatgpt to learn programming it can be a useful tool if the person has a hard time reading documentation.

Comment: @darclander How can it be a useful tool, when a lot of the time it produces convincing looking things that are either wrong or totally inappropriate/insecure.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I understand the frustration people might have with ChatGPT but to call it a *nonsense generator*, I would say is factually wrong. It *can* provide very helpful code but it *could* also give you something completely useless. That is why we should always take the output with a grain of salt. I still believe it can be a useful learning tool. If it can help you find mistakes in your code or hint at where you might be wrong. When I am learning I don't go to a manual and 100% rely on it. I use every tool available to learn as much as possible.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I apologize. I think I understand better why you advice people to not use it as a learning tool. I still believe it *could* be useful but I think too many people rely on it.

Answer (score -2):

As mentioned in comments, the right way to do this is using system property. In my case new code looks like this:
`URL url = Paths.get(System.getProperty("java.class.path")).toAbsolutePath().toUri().toURL();`

Comment: A URL’s path portion is *not* the same as a filename.  The correct way to convert a single filename to a URL is `Paths.get(filename).toAbsolutePath().toUri().toURL()`.  However, the classpath can contain multiple paths, separated by [pathSeparatorChar](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#pathSeparatorChar).  Assuming it only contains one file path will eventually burn you.

Comment: thanks @VGR, posted an edit.